# The type or namespace name 'DefaultHttpRequest' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have just upgraded to .net core 3.1 from 2.1.

I updated all the packages but i am getting the below errors which I am not able to resolve:

```
The type or namespace name 'DefaultHttpRequest' could not be found 
The type or namespace name 'Internal' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http'
```

I have been using above as:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.**Internal**;

 private static async Task<UserInfo>
            Uplpoad(byte[] buffer, FormFileCollection formFileCollection,
                **DefaultHttpRequest defaultHttpRequest,**
                Dictionary<string, StringValues> dictionary)
  {
   //some code
    defaultHttpRequest.Form = new FormCollection(dictionary, formFileCollection);
   //some code

   }

  public async void  Test1Up()
  { 
    //some code
    var defaultHttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(featureCollection);
    var defaultHttpRequest = new **DefaultHttpRequest**(defaultHttpContext);
    //some code
  }
```

See the error in the highlighted lines in **

I can see in the breaking changes for 3.1 there are changes to DefaultHttpContext but I didn't find anything related to `DefaultHttpRequest` which is giving me errors as above.

Comment: instead of using DefaultHttpRequest directly, can you use something like var context = new DefaultHttpContext(); and fetch the 'Request' from the within the context like var defaultHttpRequest = context.Request;

Comment: The error as I mentioned is by using DefaultHttpRequest

Comment: have you specifically gone through this doc already - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1#http-defaulthttpcontext-extensibility-removed ?

Comment: Yes so that also mentions DefaultHttpContext changes but I am having errors in DefaultHttpRequest

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DefaultHttpRequest` was changed from `public` to `internal` as part of the ASP.NET Core 3.0 release, which means it's no longer available. In the code you've shown, there doesn't appear to be any reason to create or depend on `DefaultHttpRequest`.

I recommend changing the code to something like this:

```
private static async Task<UserInfo> Upload(byte[] buffer, FormFileCollection formFileCollection,
    HttpRequest httpRequest, Dictionary<string, StringValues> dictionary)
{
    // ...

    httpRequest.Form = new FormCollection(dictionary, formFileCollection);

    // Update all other references to defaultHttpRequest

    // ...
}

public async void Test1Up() // async void is generally bad, but that's a separate issue
{ 
    // ...

    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(featureCollection);
    var httpRequest = httpContext.Request;

    // Update all other references to defaultHttpContext and defaultHttpRequest

    // ...
}
```

Rather than passing around `DefaultHttpRequest`, use the abstract `HttpRequest`. The `Form` property being set in `Upload` is part of `HttpRequest`, so that should work as-is. There's also no need to *create* an instance of `DefaultHttpRequest`: the `DefaultHttpContext` constructor does this for you and provides it via its `Request` property.

Here's the official [announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/377) and relevant [linked issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11312).