# ASP.net migration from 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
if (((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest)HttpContext.Request).Method == "GET")
{
//code
}
```

The type or namespace name 'Internal' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?

this is my current packagereferences

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeCoverage" Version="16.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="5.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Owin" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: what is the context of your if-statement? where are you using it?

Comment: Why are you casting at all? It should work just like `if (HttpContext.Request.Method == "GET")` ...

Comment: The `Internal` namespaces are just that - internal implementation details. they can be broken at anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160744/the-type-or-namespace-name-defaulthttprequest-could-not-be-found),refer to what `serpent5` said,

> DefaultHttpRequest was changed from public to internal as part of the
> ASP.NET Core 3.0 release, which means it's no longer available.

And in your code,you use`(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest)HttpContext.Request).Method== "GET"` .You can try to use `HttpContext.Request.Method== "GET"` without using `DefaultHttpRequest`.Here is the official link of [HttpContext.Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.request?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_Request) and [HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-5.0).