# CS0234:The type or namespace 'Internal' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspnetCore.Http'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: asp.net-core

I get this error while migrating from .netcore2.2 to 3.0 .I have replaced request.EnableRewind() with request.EnableBuffering and the code does not use Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest([ASP.net migration from 2.2 to 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68832071/asp-net-migration-from-2-2-to-3-1)).
Are there any changes to be made for HttpRequest or HttpContext in the 3.0 version?
Any help would be appreciated
-Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to `"Pubternal" APIs removed` in the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.0),and you can see

> To better maintain the public API surface of ASP.NET Core, most of the types in *.Internal namespaces (referred to as "pubternal" APIs) have become truly internal. Members in these namespaces were never meant to be supported as public-facing APIs. The APIs could break in minor releases and often did. Code that depends on these APIs breaks when updating to ASP.NET Core 3.0.

If you are using `HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();`,try to use `HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();` to replace it.

> In an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project, replace the EnableRewind call with a call to the EnableBuffering extension method. The request buffering feature works as it did in the past. EnableBuffering calls the now internal API.

Answer (score 1):

The internal namespace was made really internal as part of .NET Core 3.1.
If any one is looking for a similar solution while using IFormFile in .net core 6 (or above 3.1), you have to modify the .csproj file as shown below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CSharpFunctionalExtensions" Version="2.29.1" />
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This is the only solution that worked for me.
More more info, refer https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41522

Also note that, if you are creating an IFormFile from a MemoryStream (or byte Array), that will succeed only from Controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` in your `.csproject` and see that if it resolves.

You can find more details related to this issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41522).